# Generate files for excel safe and efficient

Tags: .net, excel

I want to create a software probably  in .NET or JAVA that will be connected with a digital scale. I want exported data to be able to open with Excel. What are my options ?

- CSV file ?
- Excel interop .net library?
- Other?

I guess csv is a solution but doesnt allow any extra stuff.. However i dont want data to be lost so i think that in case of computer crash using interop .net file maybe be corrupted.
In case with csv it wont be corrupted. Is there any alternative solution ?

Comment: What makes you think that a different file format will save you from random corruptions?

Comment: csv wont corrupt the whole file ,but with another file format it might be hard to see any line...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd prefer CSV as it is easier to move around from one system/language to another with fewer codes to change [Java to .Net or .Net to Java]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create Excel files, try to use [OpenXML](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=5124) or [some lib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151005/create-excel-xls-and-xlsx-file-from-c-sharp), which wrap it.
To find some data in already existed file, [OleDb](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8500/Reading-and-Writing-Excel-using-OLEDB) can be faster.